# Replace a part of string using replace method

Tags: javascript, replace

i just want to know the replace function in js to convert the below text to another.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Alloy Ink";
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url("alloy-ink.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

it is stored as a string in variable data. In this src needs to be replaced  and it should look like:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Alloy Ink";
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@creative-fonts/alloy-ink/alloy-ink.otf")
    format("opentype");
}
```

Also `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@creative-fonts/alloy-ink/alloy-ink.otf` is stored in a variable named fonturl.

Comment: That's what `String.replace` does, have you tried reading the docs? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: yes but i am unable to form a regex expression for it

Comment: You don't need a regex, just replace the string `'alloy-ink.otf'` with `fonturl`.

Comment: actually that url will keep changing so i have to replace the whole url

Comment: Please clarify your question then, what portions of the input are dynamic, do you need to use the input url in the fonturl?

Comment: there are different files for different fonts i am fetching from a cdn, after fetching , i have to replace only the url of that with fonturl and then store the changed string in a variable to be used again

Comment: I updated my answer, not sure I understand, but maybe it is close to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple.

```js
css.replace(/url\(".+?"\)/, `url("${fonturl}")`)
```